# Income tax returns acknowledgement upon processing

Tags: income-tax, india

In India, does the income tax department send acknowledgements after processing incomes tax returns? I know that they send acknowledgement mails after the returns are e-verified. But I specifically want to know whether they send an acknowledgement after processing the income tax return.

Answer (score 1):

Its not consistent. Few years I got email confirmation that returns have been processed, few years I didn't get any. It doesn't make much difference as the acknowledgement of submission is sufficient.

If you need it explicit, pay few rupees more in taxes and you will get acknowledgement after processing... note refund is done only if the  amount is more than Rs 100(?) And not for small amounts.

Comment: Thank you. How do I pay more in tax in return for an acknowledgement of processing? I did not see any option for doing that while paying my tax due. I am not owed a refund, but I still want to know whether my return was processed without any issues.

Comment: @user2371765 pay self assessment taxes via online payment and enter the details in tax paid, it would automatically calculate refund

Comment: I already filed my return and paid extra tax. Is this what you call self-assessment tax? I don't think there is any refund. I just want to be sure that the returns have been processed and accepted. I don't want anything to crop up four months later when I least expect it.